# Internet Explorer sees an Internet Page as "Intranet" page and shows it in Compatibility View

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

We have a certain Internet page which needs to be accessed by 5000+ employees.
However, many of them reported that the page is not displayed correctly.

After some troubleshooting we figured out that the page is displayed in Compatibility View.

The setting "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is turned on for everybody.
Unchecking this option solves the problem.
However, this is very weird because the page is an Internet page. Not intranet nor related to our own domain whatsoever.
It's a training portal hosted in the cloud.

The site is not listed in the "Local intranet" sites in IE.

This issues occurs for approx. 50 of our users.

The question is...
Why is this Internet page seen as an intranet page on some devices?
How can IE classify this page as an intranet page?

Comment: I suggest you to provide detailed information about your issue. Which OS and which version of IE you are using? Those machines are installed with latest updates or not? try to provide the URL of that site which is not displaying properly. Try to reset the IE and check whether it solves the issue or not.

Comment: I actually figured out why this is happening.
But to answer your questions first:
- IE 11
- Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 with latest updates


The issue occurs because we are using a Cloud hosted PAC file for webfiltering. (Forcepoint)
Only when the PAC file is used, this site is seen as an intranet site.
If no PAC file is used, the site displays correctly, no matter what the compatibility settings are.

They also have an article for that:
https://support.forcepoint.com/KBArticle?id=Sites-Display-Incorrectly-with-IE-When-Configured-to-use-Hosted-Web-PAC-File

Comment: It looks like you had find the cause for the issue. I suggest you to post it as an answer for this thread and mark it as an answer may help other community members in future.